# Ignore string in SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, e-commerce

I've been using the function below to list products within an A to Z directory on a WordPress/WooCommerce site. E.g. visiting `site.com/a-to-z/?letter=a` would show a catalogue of products beginning with A.

```
function wpse_298888_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $starts_with = $query->get( 'starts_with' );

    if ( $starts_with ) {
      $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '$starts_with%'";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_298888_posts_where', 10, 2 );
```

This has been working great, but the client has now changed the way that they're naming their products, so a majority of them are now prefixed with phrases like "Char Grilled" or "Pan Fried" etc. For example "Steak" has now become "Char Grilled Steak". This means that the function above isn't really working as we want it to any more, so is there any way to alter the SQL query so that it will ignore a predefined set of phrases like "Char Grilled", "Pan Fried" and so on?

Comment: Can you have a searchable name and a display name, this allows more flexibility.

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to prefix the search string with a percent sign? Changing your 7th line in the example above to `$where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$starts_with%'";` ? might be slower, as you lose the possibility for searching for a range predicate , but should work ....

Comment: Erk.. Concatenating a value supplied by a web user straight into your db query? This is a hack just waiting to happen. Which bank do you work for?

Comment: The title of my post is `' and 1=0 union all select username, password from user --`

Comment: You would generally accomplish such matching with a negative lookbehind regex, which however isn't supported by MySQL regexp. You could hypothetically do an on-the-fly regexp replace on the selected column that deletes any leading `^(char grilled|pan fried) ` etc. before matching the initial letter. This would however be hideously expensive and your indexes would be useless. What @NigelRen said, simply have a separate (indexed) search name column. If A-Z is a staple feature, for better performance still, just have a column for the letter the product should be filed under.

Comment: @marcothesane with your query, a query for "R" would match "Cha**r** G**r**illed F**r**ench F**r**ies", etc. and any item containing the letter "r" anywhere.

Comment: In that case, you would be forced to foresee each and every group of words preceding what you're looking for; put those in a `prefixes` table; then, `CROSS JOIN ` your query with  the `prefixes` table; concatenate each prefix with the string you're looking for, and filter...